# How does one show untracked files in current directory only (ignoring subdirectories)?

Tags: git

```
git ls-files --others
```

goes down the directory tree.  Is there an easy way to show untracked files *only* in the current directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the exclude pattern of [`ls-files`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html):

```
 # on Windows, with msysgit
 git ls-files --others -x */*

 # on Unix (Cygwin or Ubuntu), quotes are necessary around the pattern
 git ls-files --others -x "*/*"
```

From the man page:

```
-x <pattern>
--exclude=<pattern>
```

> Skip untracked files matching pattern. Note that pattern is a shell wildcard pattern.

Comment: Accepting this as a more general solution (but `grep -v /` is a good answer).  Note that the pattern needs to be quoted ("*/*").

Comment: @Leo: did you need the quotes? in my msysgit 1.7.4, I didn't need to use them around the exclude pattern.

Comment: Better :) For some reason I thought `-x` only matches on the basename

Comment: yeah, this didn't work for me w/o the quotes under either Cygwin (1.7.3.3) or Ubuntu (can't check version right now)

Answer (score 2):

<del>I don't think there's an option to `git ls-files` that has that effect</del>, but you could always just do:

```
git ls-files --other | grep -v /
```

... to just list the untracked files in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the current directory is the top of the repo, you can do this

```bsh
git ls-files -iox "/*"
```