# How does one show untracked files in current directory only while using .gitignore filter?

Tags: git

As a followup on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741106/)

The answer there show all untracked files. How to show untracked files in current directory only, and use the .gitignore, i.e. files in .gitignore shouldnt be shown?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `git status --ignored`

Comment: Result is: `error: unknown option ignored`

Comment: you must be running an ancient version of git. `status` has had the `ignored` option since at least [version 1.8.1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/1.8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are not quite clear.

If you want to see only untracked files that *match* the `.gitignore` filter then

```
git ls-files --other --exclude-standard --ignored|grep -v /
```

If you want to see only untracked files that *do not match* the `.gitignore` filter then

```
git ls-files --other --exclude-standard|grep -v /
```

Used options of `git ls-files`:

> `-o, --others`   Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
>
> `-i, --ignored`  Show only ignored files in the output. When showing
>   files in the index, print only those matched by an exclude pattern.
>   **When showing "other" files, show only those matched by an exclude
>   pattern.**
>
> `--exclude-standard`  Add the standard Git exclusions:
>   `.git/info/exclude`, `.gitignore` in each directory, and the user’s global
>   exclusion file.

Files not from the current directory are filtered out with `grep`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still see files that should be ignored

Comment: @user2476373 So which files do you want to be shown, and which files you want to be ignored?

Comment: Thanks. `git ls-files --other --exclude-standard|grep -v /` works. I clarified my question, for future readers.